# panda: dropping multiple columns and keeping only ones with numeric data

Tags: python, pandas

I need to clean my data frame and remove all columns without numeric data. I have columns with are classified as "object" and some marked as int/float, but containing mostly NaNs. I would like to keep only columns filled with numbers. Is there way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html?highlight=select_dtypes#pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes) and pass `np.number` to filter numeric types only:

```
In [69]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'int':np.arange(5), 'float':np.random.randn(5), 'str':list('abcde')})
df

Out[69]:
      float  int str
0  0.987218    0   a
1  0.336119    1   b
2  1.800194    2   c
3  4.566850    3   d
4 -0.306808    4   e

In [71]:    
df.select_dtypes([np.number])

Out[71]:
      float  int
0  0.987218    0
1  0.336119    1
2  1.800194    2
3  4.566850    3
4 -0.306808    4
```

This accepts any type in the [numpy type hierarchy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html)

To remove columns that contain any `NaN`s then you can call `dropna(axis=1)` thanks @Leb

Comment: If I understand correctly he wants to drop columns that have `NaN` in them. So you'll need to add `.dropna(axis=1)`

Comment: @Leb yes I missed that part

Comment: Thanks to everybody, your replies helped!

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm new here.